# error at react redux combinereducer with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, dispatch, reducers

I'm trying to learn redux by making a to-do list

but i am getting an error and i couldn't solve this problem

my types

```
  export interface TodoType {
  text: string;
  id: number;
}
export interface TodoState {
  todoList: TodoType[];
}

interface ADD_TODO {
  type: "ADD_TODO";
  payload: TodoType;
}
interface REMOVE_TODO {
  type: "REMOVE_TODO";
  payload: TodoType;
}
export interface AppState {
  todo: TodoState;
}
export type TodoAction = ADD_TODO | REMOVE_TODO;
```

TodoReducer.ts ;

```
import { TodoState, TodoAction } from "global";

const INITIAL_STATE: TodoState = {
  todoList: [],
};

export const TodoReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action: TodoAction) => {
  console.log(state, action);
};
```

index.ts

```
import { TodoState } from "global";
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { TodoReducer } from "./reducers/TodoReducer";

export interface AppState {
  todo: TodoState;
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers<AppState>({
  todo: TodoReducer,
});
export default rootReducer;
```

here I am getting error in todo: part
[image]

index.ts of my file

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

import App from "./App";
import rootReducer from "./store";

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,

  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I will be very glad if you can help me how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `TodoReducer` should return `TodoState` types at all times.

Currently, you are only logging `state` and `action` inside your reducer. Fill it up and it should work fine.

Comment: Your answer isn't clear enough

Answer (score 0):

While it's not quite a direct answer to your question, you should really switch to using our official Redux Toolkit package, which is the standard approach for writing Redux logic. It will simplify your code, let you eliminate all of those extra action and type definitions, *and* works great with TS:

https://redux.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript

Example:

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import type { RootState } from '../../app/store'

// Define a type for the slice state
interface CounterState {
  value: number
}

// Define the initial state using that type
const initialState: CounterState = {
  value: 0
}

export const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'counter',
  // `createSlice` will infer the state type from the `initialState` argument
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    increment: state => {
      state.value += 1
    },
    decrement: state => {
      state.value -= 1
    },
    // Use the PayloadAction type to declare the contents of `action.payload`
    incrementByAmount: (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
      state.value += action.payload
    }
  }
})

export const { increment, decrement, incrementByAmount } = counterSlice.actions

// Other code such as selectors can use the imported `RootState` type
export const selectCount = (state: RootState) => state.counter.value

export default counterSlice.reducer
```